# Example of use pwm_get() in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, pwm

I want to try to use PWM in linux kernel module for my Rasperry Pi. I've successfully enabled PWM via SYSFS interface. 
For usage of pwm in kernel modules documentation states:

> New users should use the pwm_get() function and pass to it the
>   consumer device or a consumer name. pwm_put() is used to free the PWM
>   device. Managed variants of these functions, devm_pwm_get() and
>   devm_pwm_put(), also exist.

pwm_get function looks like this:

```
/**
 * pwm_get() - look up and request a PWM device
 * @dev: device for PWM consumer
 * @con_id: consumer name
....
 */
struct pwm_device *pwm_get(struct device *dev, const char *con_id)
```

Where I can find dev and con_id? I suspect that they should be defined in device tree, but it is only a suspicion.

Comment: Use [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) to search the kernel for any identifiers or strings you're looking for.

Comment: You have to provide resources via a) device tree, or b) ACPI (however, there it would be done in another way), or c) static lookup tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One example of `pwm_get()` is available in the [Intel PWM backlight
>   panel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_panel.c?v=4.9#L1657) driver.
>   Here it is being used to obtain a PWM source by its name.
>
> ```
> /* Get the PWM chip for backlight control */
> panel->backlight.pwm = pwm_get(dev->dev, "pwm_backlight");
> ```
>
> The PWM provider itself is defined
>   [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/intel_soc_pmic_core.c?v=4.9#L42)...
>
> ```
> /* PWM consumed by the Intel GFX */
> static struct pwm_lookup crc_pwm_lookup[] = {
>         PWM_LOOKUP("crystal_cove_pwm", 0, "0000:00:02.0", "pwm_backlight", 0, PWM_POLARITY_NORMAL),
> };
> ```
>
> ...and initialised
>   [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/intel_soc_pmic_core.c?v=4.9#L109).
>
> ```
> /* Add lookup table for crc-pwm */
> pwm_add_table(crc_pwm_lookup, ARRAY_SIZE(crc_pwm_lookup));
> ```

---

[**`pwm-beeper`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/misc/pwm-beeper.c?v=4.9#L105) is another example of `pwm_get()`.

```
beeper->pwm = pwm_get(&pdev->dev, NULL);
```

A corresponding entry in the device tree is present [**here**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/s3c6410-mini6410.dts?v=4.9#L161).

```
buzzer {
        compatible = "pwm-beeper";
        pwms = <&pwm 0 1000000 0>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pwm0_out>;
};
```

---

> The [inline documentation of `pwm_get()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pwm/core.c?v=4.9#L742) describes both the ways it can be used.

```
/**
* pwm_get() - look up and request a PWM device
* @dev: device for PWM consumer
* @con_id: consumer name
*
* Lookup is first attempted using DT. If the device was not instantiated from
* a device tree, a PWM chip and a relative index is looked up via a table
* supplied by board setup code (see pwm_add_table()).
*
* Once a PWM chip has been found the specified PWM device will be requested
* and is ready to be used.
*
* Returns: A pointer to the requested PWM device or an ERR_PTR()-encoded
* error code on failure.
*/
```